# Redshift copy json from S3 fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-copy-from-json) documents, I was trying to load JSON Data from S3 to RedShift.
Created JSONPath file & validated (on https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/# with expression `$.*`)

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$['_record_id']",
        "$['_title']",
        "$['_server_updated_at']",
        "$['_project']",
        "$['_assigned_to']",
        "$['_updated_by']",
        "$['_latitude']",
        "$['_longitude']",
        "$['date']",
        "$['date_received']",
        "$['inspection_type']"
    ]
}
```

and sample data

```
[{
    "_record_id": "cf68c930-b7c8-4c3f-a04c-58b49f383cca",
    "_title": "FAIL, 128",
    "_server_updated_at": "2021-08-03T15:06:05.000Z",
    "_project": null,
    "_assigned_to": null,
    "_updated_by": "XYZ",
    "_geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-74.5048900706, 40.3395964363]
    },
    "_latitude": 40.3395964363,
    "_longitude": -74.5048900706,
    "date": "2021-08-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_received": "2021-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "inspection_type": "New Product Inspection"
}, {
    "_record_id": "9c8af79a-eaaf-405e-8c42-62560fdf15d5",
    "_title": "PASS, 52",
    "_server_updated_at": "2021-08-03T14:56:23.000Z",
    "_project": null,
    "_assigned_to": null,
    "_updated_by": "XYZ",
    "_geometry": null,
    "_latitude": null,
    "_longitude": null,
    "date": "2021-08-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_received": "2021-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "inspection_type": "New Product Inspection"
}]
```

When I run this COPY command

```
copy rab.rab_dbo.shipmentreceivinglog2
from 's3://<bucket>/data_report.json'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/RedshiftFileTransfer'
json 's3://<bucket>g/JSONPaths.json';
```

I get `ERROR: Load into table 'shipmentreceivinglog2' failed. Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.` When I run `select * from stl_load_errors;` I see

`Invalid JSONPath format: Member is not an object.` for `s3://<bucket>/data_report.json`

Whats wrong with my JSONPath File ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon Redshift error while copying json file - Invalid JSONPath format: Member is not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899762/amazon-redshift-error-while-copying-json-file-invalid-jsonpath-format-member)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your data file.  Redshift json input data needs to be a set of json records just smashed together. You have a file that is one json array of objects.  An array is one thing.  You need to take out the enclosing [] and the commas between elements.  Your sample data should look like

```
{
    "_record_id": "cf68c930-b7c8-4c3f-a04c-58b49f383cca",
    "_title": "FAIL, 128",
    "_server_updated_at": "2021-08-03T15:06:05.000Z",
    "_project": null,
    "_assigned_to": null,
    "_updated_by": "XYZ",
    "_geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-74.5048900706, 40.3395964363]
    },
    "_latitude": 40.3395964363,
    "_longitude": -74.5048900706,
    "date": "2021-08-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_received": "2021-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "inspection_type": "New Product Inspection"
}
{
    "_record_id": "9c8af79a-eaaf-405e-8c42-62560fdf15d5",
    "_title": "PASS, 52",
    "_server_updated_at": "2021-08-03T14:56:23.000Z",
    "_project": null,
    "_assigned_to": null,
    "_updated_by": "XYZ",
    "_geometry": null,
    "_latitude": null,
    "_longitude": null,
    "date": "2021-08-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_received": "2021-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "inspection_type": "New Product Inspection"
}
```

An easy way to get this is to pump the json you have through jq.

```
jq '.[]' file.json
```